# Why does my UICollectionViewController not show anything?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a UICollectionViewController show a grid of cells (in which I'll later add text, likely as textViews if possible). I have:

```
class GridViewController : UICollectionViewController{

    //(NOW GONE) @IBOutlet weak var gridViewTable = UICollectionViewController()

    let arr1 : [String] = []
    let arr2 : [String] = []


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridCell")


    }

   func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }




    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    }
}
```

I used the interface builder to connect white where the cells will go to the gridViewTable. Nothing shows up at all, even tho it runs and compiles. How can I get the cells to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use these code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @Derry you weren't overriding the functions already contained with `UICollectionViewController`, you were redefining them yourself. I missed that when I first answered your question.

Comment: also, on my storyboard, I dragged and dropped a TextView into the prototype cells because I want the cells to fill with text pulled from a 2D array. How can I get those textviews filled?

Comment: correction; they're labels, not textviews. How can I get them filled in each cell, from a 2D array of Strings?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outlet for a `UICollectionViewController`, the class itself takes care of that.

Also, make sure that the view controller's class in Interface Builder is set to `GridViewController` in the Identity Inspector (3rd tab from the left in the right-most pane).

Comment: I got rid of the outlet and now my program crashes when I try to go to the GridViewController

Comment: Make sure you delete the outlet from Interface Builder too

Comment: thanks, it no longer crashes! But there are still no cells showing up